# Replace non numeric content of pandas column

Tags: python, regex, pandas, replace

I want to delete all non numerical characters of a column of my pandas dataframe. I use this line :

```
     df.column.str.replace('[\D]', '')
```

When I applied this on the first column, I got the second one, but I want the third :

```
Column                               Column after Replace        Desired output
330301 = 330324                      330301330324                330301330324

330381                               NaN                         330381

355047                               NaN                         355047

ALL 380307 / 380343                  380307380343                380307380343
```

The first and the last lines are expected outputs but I don't want to delete other values. I don't see why it is made.

Comment: can you post a proper dataframe and expected output. Its a little unclear how this happens

Comment: It's beyond a "little unclear", it's totally unclear. You need a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
pattern = re.compile('\D')
df[0].replace(pattern, '')
```

[image]